# gitignore not ignoring changes to folder with heroku

Tags: python, git, flask, heroku

I have a flask heroku app that uploads files to a folder and allows users to view those files.

Essentially, once a file is uploaded, it saves it into `static/uploads`.

However, everytime I publish new changes with `git add .`, `git commit -m "changes"`, `git push heroku master`, it resets the static/uploads folder without the files that have been uploaded on the heroku app. This is happening because the static/uploads folder on my local that I am committing is empty.

I want the folder on the heroku server to keep all the files in it, even after I publish the new changes. To do this, I tried adding `static/uploads` into my `.gitignore` file however this did not help...

Can someone please help...?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to remove `static/uploads` from both production and local.

- Commit the changes after removing the folder
- Add `static/uploads` to .gitignore
- Create `static/uploads` again and then commit the changes

**Note:**
You'll lose all your files, i would suggest to keep a backup first, once the folder starts getting ignored, you can then add the files again

Comment: when u say commit the changes (step 3). Does that mean create the static/uploads and then do `git add .`, `git commit -m "changes"`, `git push heroku master` or just do `git commit -m "changes"` and then `git push heroku master`? @HarshitRastogi

Comment: Also, what does this mean going forwards... Do I have to do this everytime I want to make changes to my heroku app without getting rid of whatever is in the uploads folder on the heroku app? @HarshitRastogi

Comment: first of all we are going to remove the folder from the repo and then commit the changes without creating the folder. Then after the commit, add the folder in gitignore and then commit again. No, you don't have to do this everytime, it's just one time when we need to remove the tracking of this folder in our repo so that this folder can be independent of the environment